# Struggling to get this to upload into my database

Tags: php, image, upload

```
// Check his status.
if (!empty($_SESSION[username]))
{
echo "Hi, <b>$_SESSION[username]</b>.";

if ($_POST['submit'])
{

    //get file attributes
    $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

if ($name)
{
    //start upload process

    $location = "avatars/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);

        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE username='$username'");

        die("Your image has been uploaded! <a href='dashboard.php'>Back</a>");


}
else
die("Please select file");
}
echo "upload your image:

<form action='profile.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/formdata'>

File: <input type='file' name='myfile'> <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}
```

Its showing the username fine, I have the correct tables and columns in the db but when you hit upload it does nothing?

You can see it for yourself by logging in as username: test password: test url: learning.iamdanbarrett.com

Comment: Define "does nothing".

Comment: Hi Tim, Well it failt to load the image into the DB and the confirmation message does not show

Comment: Struggling does describe well your feelings but not a programming question. Try to isolate the problem by trouble-shooting away the parts that work and then ask the concrete programming question where you want to learn about. Try to prevent asking questions that sound like guessing and inviting others to guess what your code does or does not. I therefore voted to close your question as "Not a real question" in the hope that you edit it for good.

Comment: Hold on Sir I have not opened this up fopr debate on asknig for people to do it for me, I have asked an honest question as to why this is not sending the data to my DB and what I have missed? Is this not a website for guidence and assistance?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in your query

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE username='$username'");
```

because you are not defining $username variable anywhere in script hence, your query is checking like

```
UPDATE members SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE username ='';
```

Comment: I have swapped the code and again still the same results as I mentioned.

Comment: "Swapped the code"? What do you mean? May I also comment that you should not be storing usernames as a reference - that is the job for user IDs.

Comment: Hi Tim, so what do you suggest I change this too?

Answer (score 0):

**if ($_POST['submit'])** should be **if ($_POST['Submit'])** as your submit button name starts with capital **S** and not small s

Comment: This has not resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you share your whole php file? You have only attached portion of it in this question

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ($_POST['submit'])
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Comment: Where shall I add this? or what am I replacing?

Comment: That has still not changed anything :(